# Solve the Wave Equation $u_{tt} - c^2u_{xx} = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The initial values are as follows:

$$u(x, 0) = f(x) \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, u_t(x, 0) = g(x)$$

Let $v = u_t$ and $w = u_x$.  I was able to obtain the characteristic lines $x = \pm ct + r$, and arrive at:
$$u_t = g(x - ct) \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, u_t = g(x + ct)$$
This is where I am stuck at.  If I just integrate with respect to $t$, I have:
$$u = \int_{0}^{\, t} g(x - cs) \, ds + F(x) \, \, \rightarrow \, \, u(0, x) = F(x) = f(x)$$
So, $u = \int_{0}^{\, t} g(x - cs) \, ds + f(x)$.  Now, double-check:
\begin{align*}
u_t & = g(x - ct) \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, \, u_{tt} =-cg'(x - ct) \\ \\
u_x & = \int_{0}^{\, t} g'(x - cs) \, dx + f'(x) \\
u_{xx} & = \int_{0}^{\, t} g''(x - cs) \, dx + f''(x)
\end{align*}

Put them all together:

\begin{align}
u_{tt} - c^2u_{xx} & = -cg'(x - ct) - c^2 \int_{0}^{\, t} g''(x-cs) \, - c^2f''(x) \\
& = -cg'(x - ct) + c \int_{0}^{-ct} g''(x+u) \, du - c^2f''(x) \\
& = -cg'(x - ct) + cg'(x - ct) - c^2f''(x) \\
& = -cf''(x)
\end{align}

What did I apply wrong?  My solution makes it look like that $f$ must be linear.

Comment: Your first three lines don't really make sense to me. First, did you manage to construct the general solution to the wave equation (something like $u = f(x-ct) + g(x+ct)$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution to the wave equation is

$$u(x,t)=\phi(x+ct)+\psi(x-ct) \tag1$$

Applying the initial conditions $u(x,0)=f(x)$ and $u_t(x,0)=g(x)$ to $(1)$ yields the set of equations

$$\begin{align}
\phi'(x)+\psi'(x)&=f'(x) \tag 2\\\\
\phi'(x)-\psi'(x)&=\frac1cg(x)\tag 3
\end{align}$$

Solving $(2)$ and $(3)$ simultaneously reveals

$$\phi(x)=\frac12 f(x)+\frac{1}{2c}\int_0^tg(x')\,dx'+A \tag 4$$

$$\psi(x)=\frac12 f(x)-\frac{1}{2c}\int_0^tg(x')\,dx'+B \tag 5$$

where $A$ and $B$ are integration constants.

Using $(4)$ and $(5)$ in $(1)$, we obtain

$$u(x,t)=\frac12(f(x+ct)+f(x-ct))+\frac1{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}g(x')\,dx'+A+B \tag 6$$

Since $u(x,0)=f(x)$, we find that $A=B=0$ and we can write $(6)$ as

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{u(x,t)=\frac12(f(x+ct)+f(x-ct))+\frac1{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}g(x')\,dx'}$$